# Comparision between MongoClient and MongoDB. Why MongoClient is better?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-5.6, php-7

I don't like the new mongo, MongoDB require several libs in PHP7.

**MongoClient (deprecated) in php 5 is much more comfortable and lightweight!**

I have decided to launch a script and comparing the two versions and the results are quite surprising:

**MongoDB (PHP 7.0.2)**

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client(
    'mongodb://root:password@localhost:port',
    ['readPreference' => 'secondaryPreferred']
);
$db = $client->selectDatabase('namedb');
$collection = $client->selectCollection('namedb', 'test');
$document   = $collection->findOne(['_id' => 'works']);
var_dump($document);
$time       = microtime();
$time       = explode(' ', $time);
$time       = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish     = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo '<br><br>Page generated in ' . $total_time . ' seconds.';
```

**Mongo/MongoClient (PHP 5.6.17)**

```
$db = new MongoClient('mongodb://root:password@localhost:port');
$c  = $db->namedb->test;
$a  = $c->findOne(array("_id" => 'works'));
var_dump($a);
$time       = microtime();
$time       = explode(' ', $time);
$time       = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish     = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo '<br><br>Page generated in ' . $total_time . ' seconds.';
```

[image: Comparision between MongoClient (PHP 7.0.2) and MongoDB(PHP 5.6.17)]

**Anyone else experience this problem?
I can't find any benefit in using the new version of MongoDB, all are problems!**

Comment: `MongoDB` only offers a low level API. If you want a higher level API like the MongoDB driver delivers for other languages, you need to use the PHPLib of MongoDB. Check the php manual about MongoDB, the phplib is linked there.

Comment: Also you need to use `microtime(true)`! Without the argument set to `true` you will get a string returned, which will get you wrong results in math operations.

Comment: `$start = microtime(true); ....your mongodb operations... $totaltime = microtime(true) - $start;` Really no need to explode or anything.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I already had installed and look at the result.

Comment: I did and you have to redo your tests. Do your time math operations correctly.

Comment: Thanks @CharlotteDunois but I 've tried microtime changes but the results are similar ...


The problem is the difference in performance between Mongo (which only has low level libraries ) and MongoDB (which has high-level libraries ) that makes dependence have phplib and composer.

Comment: `Mongo` (the deprecated extension) offers a high level API. `MongoDB` only offers straight from the extension a low level API. Well, I don't use MongoDB so I don't mind any performance differences. You might wanna bug the php team.

Comment: Github issues would be a more productive place to ask such questions ... a regression in performance is a regression all the same, there are going to be differences but I'm sure the maintainers would like to know about this whatever ...

Answer (score 0):

`MongoClient` is a native driver written as a PHP extension.

`MongoDB` is PHP code which uses a different PHP extension. I presume the new extension is easier to maintain as it shares the `libmongoc` library used by projects other than PHP.

Comparing a native driver to a PHP library is an unfair comparison.  If you want to compare performance you should try one native driver directly against the other.

> I can't find any benefit in using the new version of MongoDB

First and foremost, the older `MongoClient` extension is deprecated.  It will only live on if you or others choose to pick it up and maintain it.  Although having two similar libraries for the same task would be confusing (see mysql vs mysqli).

`MongoDB` is meant to provide a higher level of abstraction and you can probably expect to see more frequent feature updates than to a native driver.